# Detect if the FreeType PHP extension is installed on the server

Tags: php, php-extension, freetype

How do I test to see if the FreeType extension is installed on a server running PHP?

I wanted to make a simple CAPTCHA system on my site, so I used [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) and it worked fine. But what if the server didn't have the FreeType library installed?

So is there a way to somehow detect FreeType library through code, and if it is not present, fall back to something like [`imagestring()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php)?

If I can't use `imagettftext()` I may have to look at alternatives to draw big font text as the `imagestring` max size isn't good for something like a CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php):

```
if (function_exists('imagettftext')) {
     imagettftext();
} else {
     // do other function
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 this does not a check if freetype is installed, but a check if a function imagettftext is available - but this should work in the given context

Comment: :) I was just hoping to point this person in a correct direction.

Comment: Yes it does check for both GD and FreeType.

     [imagettftext manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

Answer (score 17):

This will not be better *in practice* than the [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) solutions already posted, but the technically correct way to check is by using [`extension_loaded`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php).

Comment: that's the easiest most effective way to  check for the extension!

Comment: @downvoter: I would so love to hear what's wrong with this answer. Thanks.

Comment: You can check for `gd` extension, but you cannot check for `freetype` simply because it's not PHP extension (see output of `php -m`). `freetype` is just linked to gd during compilation time.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the GD library is installed, you can detect Freetype support using the [gd_info()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php) function.

```
$gdinfo = gd_info();
if($gdinfo['FreeType Support']) echo 'FreeType Support Enabled';
```

If you need to check whether or not GD library is installed first, use `extension_loaded('gd');`

Answer (score 3):

This won't work for dynamic code (so not a true answer to the question) but for anyone who just want's to know if it's installed, from the command line on Linux:

```
php -i | grep -E "GD|FreeType"
```

Outputs:

```
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.2.5
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.4.11
```

NOTE: On a system without it installed you'll get no output.

Answer (score 1):

A first somewhat complicated approach:

call `php_info()` and search/parse the result for freetype

Comment: this might be complicated, but it will work (so why the downvote?)

Comment: Downvote wasn't mine, but 1) it will take effort to get it to work, 2) it's more brittle than any other solution (suppose the output of `php_info` changes in the future) and 3) it's the most computationally expensive way to do it by far.

Answer (score 0):

Try [function_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php), i.e.

```
if (!function_exists('imagettftext')) {
  // No freetype library
}
```

You'd probably be best asking for alternatives to imagettftext as a separate question.